# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Using this code in **Entity Framework** I receive the following error.

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified type
>   member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers,
>   entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

My code:

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
var result = (from c in db.orders
              where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.creationtime.Value) >= startdate

              group c by new
              {
                  date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.creationtime).Value.Date,
              }
              into g

              select new
              {
                  date = g.Key.date,

                  Total = g.Count(),
                  attend = g.Where(f => f.canceled != true && f.attindance != false).Count(),
                  notattend = g.Where(f => f.canceled != true && f.attindance == false).Count(),
                  canceled = g.Where(f => f.canceled == true).Count(),
                  other = g.Where(f => f.canceled == null && f.attindance == null).Count()
              }).OrderByDescending(m => m.date).ToList();
```

Source Error:

```
Line 156:        {
Line 157:            DateTime startdate =DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
**Line 158:            var result = (from c in db.orders**
Line 159:  where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.creationtime.Value) >= startdate 
Line 160:
```

> Source File: Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 158

Comment: Remove `.Date` from `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.creationtime).Value.Date`

Comment: thanks this fix the problem